# How to mock promise in ajax using Jest?

Tags: ajax, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

I am new to Jest and Enzyme framework and also to React.
I integrated Jest and Enzyme in one of my project but facing few issues when
mocking Ajax and it's `done()` and `fail()` part.

#### request.js

```
export function fetch(url, data = {}) {
  return $.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data,
  });
}

export function create(url, entity) {
  return $.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify(entity),
  });
}
```

#### people_form.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { create, fetch } from "request";

  fetchDuplicateRecords() {
    fetch(url, searchParams)
    .done(response => {
      this.setState({
        duplicateRecords: response,
        showDuplicateRecords: true,
      });
    })
    .fail(response => {
      this.setState({
        duplicateRecords: [],
      });
    });
}
```

I tried mocking fetch in my test file as shown below

#### people_form.test.js

```
import * as request from "request";

test("test mocking", () => {
  request.fetch = jest.fn().mockReturnValueOnce(Promise.resolve(duplicateRecords))

// expect a component is rendered. The test breaks here.
expect()
})
```

yarn test

#### I get the below error

```
fetch(url, searchParams)
    > 145 |         .done(response => {
          |          ^
          
TypeError: (0 , _request.fetch)(...).done is not a function
```

Any leads would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Where does `fetchDuplicateRecords` come from? What's `$`, do you use jQuery?

Comment: @slideshowp2 `people_form.js` file has 3 input fields `first_name`, `last_name` and `date_of_birth`. When these 3 fields are entered and they are valid we call `fetchDuplicateRecords` function. Is we use jQuery and the `fetch` function inside `fetchDuplicateRecords` is using `$.ajax` for API call.